# Windows Forms - Button clicks

Tags: c++, windows-forms-designer

I have a Windows Forms application containing around 15 different buttons which on-click should display either 1 or 0.

Now the problem: 
Currently i'm repeating almost the exact same code for each and every button and that works fine, but what i would like to do is some method that knows which button i'm currently pressing and then i would like to send that buttons name as a parameter to the function which contains the code.

**This is how i'm doing it now:**

```
    private: System::Void button1Click(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) { 
   //CODE HERE
 }
    private: System::Void button2Click(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) { 
   //SAME CODE HERE
 }
```

And this goes on until button 15...

**What i would like to do:**

```
private: System::Void justClicked(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) { 
       //CODE HERE with justClicked as the buttons name.
     }
```

Comment: The 'sender' argument tells you what button was clicked. You can use the same buttonClick method for multiple buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sender` parameter, though defined as an object, is the reference to the object that caused the event. All you have to do is cast `sender` to a Button, or Control, to get the name or whatever property you need.

You also just need a single event handler. All your buttons' Click events should be assigned to the same event handler function.